# Symmetric Functional Equation

Tags: functional-equations, symmetry

I am trying to solve this functional equation:

$$g(x)+g(1-x)=1$$

Over the reals. Unfortunately, since it's symmetric, usual tricks like trying to manipulate the expression in one of the functional summands doesn't yield anything useful. It "somewhat" resembles the [Cauchy's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) but I failed to find a way to properly link them together (probably for a good reason - see below).

On the *assumption* that g(x) is a linear function we can find it rather easy:

$$Ax+B+A(1-x)+B=1
\\
\rightarrow A = 1-2B
\\
\rightarrow g(x) = (1-2B)x+B$$

and.. it's alright, but the problem is that I want to find all functions $g(x)$ if it's possible. And I was able to prove that $g(x)$ isn't limited to just linear functions. For example, if we set $g(x) = sin^2(Ax+B)$ then by choosing $A=\frac{\pi}{2}+2B$ we get:

$$g(x)+g(1-x)=sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{2}-2Bx+B)+sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi x}{2}+2Bx-B)=
\\
sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{2}-2Bx+B)+sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}-(\frac{\pi x}{2}-2Bx+B)) = 
\\
sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{2}-2Bx+B)+cos^2(\frac{\pi x}{2}-2Bx+B) = 1$$

Thus $g(x) = sin^2((\frac{\pi}{2}-2B)x+B)$ also satisfies the equation but it's non-linear. It's obviously the same with cosine.

This begs the question - is it even possible to find all such functions $g(x)$? And if yes, how?

Comment: this has little to do with Cauchy. Take **any** odd function $h,$   that is $h(x) + h(-x)=0.$    Then define $g(x) = \frac{1}{2} + h \left( x -  \frac{1}{2}\right) $  With that, what is $g(1-x)   ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x) = f(x-1/2)+1/2$ (a graph of $g$ is a graph of $f$ shifted up and right by $1/2$), then

$$
g(x)+g(1-x)=1,\\
f(x-1/2)+1/2 +f(1-x-1/2)+1/2 = 1,\\
f(x-1/2) = −f(1/2-x).
$$

if $z=x-1/2$, we get $f(z)=-f(-z)$ a definition of an odd function. Thus $g(x)$ is any odd function shifted up and left by 1/2.